# Нахождение чисел и букв в строке. И их перемножение

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Допустим, у меня есть строка '2acacac', и мне надо найти в этой строке все цифры и перемножить их с буквами. Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял,  что вам нужно, то я бы использовал Regular expressions. Можете подробнее посмотреть в интернете

`import re
string = "2acacac"
numbers = r"\d"
result = re.findall(numbers, string)`

А дальше уже из переменной result, впринципе, можете работать

Comment: Отлично, да вы правильно поняли. А как теперь в переменную numbers сохранять только буквы?

Comment: Цифры у вас сохранены в переменной result, для букв можно сделать отдельную переменную, например symbol=r"\D", и с помрщью result_1=(symbol, string) получить отдельно буквы. Советую сайт regex101.com для тренировки.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Можете помочь с еще одной задачей: допустим, на вход подается строка по  типу: "(15a)b", и нам надо преобразовать эту строку в 15 букв a, и на последнем месте букву b, то есть 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab', как это сделать?

Comment: Впринципе,  через тот же re.findall можно достать из строки сначала цифру или число, а затем буквы. А после уже выполнить что нужно. Для того чтобы достать елиное число, а не по одной цифре, достаточно добавить после \d плюс, т.е. \d+

Comment: Пробовал, но в примере с числом 15, он воспринимает его как '1' и '5' в этом проблема.

Comment: Если использовать \d+, должно быть единым числом, по крайней мере мне так выдает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83512/discussion-between--and-karlson21).